# PHP Curl: bring HTML with redirect

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm writing a crawler with PHP that reads the HTML and stores it in a variable. The code works great if the site doesn't have a redirect. If I crawl the Google, for example, I have the following:

**CURL Result**

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=A14yVviJCuyp8wfmyIfIBg">here
</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

**PHP method**

```
private function parseHTML($url){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Apple-Tz: 0', 'X-Apple-Store-Front: 143444,12'));
    ob_start();
    curl_exec($curl); 
    curl_close($curl);
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;
}
```

How can I redirect to the destination page, crawl the HTML and return the code?

Comment: When you get that 302 page content.  Is the HTTP Status header also set to 302?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server would redirect your call, setting the **CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION** option would do the trick, maybe in conjunction with **CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS** option to limit the number of redirects. see php's [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) method

i.e.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
```

However considering in the provided example, the server is not redirecting you (your curl's request) and instead gives you (the user) some information, I'm afraid your application has to read and digest the content and does the appropriate redirection accordingly.

Comment: There is nothing to say that there is not a 302 header sent along with that content when 302 occurs such that OP could use the curl options that you rightfully suggest.  They would need to look at the response headers to see if they are truly getting a 302.  It is very common for a web server to serve custom error content along with sending an appropriate response header. You especially see this for 404 responses.

Comment: You are right @MikeBrant , thanks for the input. In which case, we could also take advantage of **CURLOPT_POSTREDIR** option to identify if it is a 302